# Upgrade php command line to 5.5.9

Tags: 14.04, php, php-cli

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I have PHP installed. When I check `phpinfo()` from browser I get 5.5.9. But when I check from command line, I get 5.3.28. How can I make the command line PHP also to 5.5.9 ? I read that this is because `php-cli` is using a different `php.ini` file.

Comment: Could you post the command line you executed and the `whereis php` output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The php command line is located in php5-cli package (`apt-cache policy php5-cli`), but since 5.3.28 has never been a part of Ubuntu, so I suspect that you have a local (compiled from sources) installation of php CLI probably in /usr/local.

Comment: you are correct @oerdnj. I manually removed the php from /usr/local/bin and then installed php5-cli in the normal way. Now I have php 5.5.9 in command line and browser

Comment: @GBRocks Please mark your question as answered then.